# How did my inactive Android phone connect to my home wifi?

Tags: android

Last night my Android phone connected to my home wifi. I made this phone inactive in 2016 because it was compromised. I could browse the internet on my phone, but my data plan was cancelled long ago, wifi was turned off, bluetooth was turned off, and mobile data was turned off. About Phone > Network was as follows:

Network: Unknown
Signal strength: 0 dBm 99 asu
Mobile network type: Unknown
Service state: Radio off
Roaming: Not roaming
Mobile network state: Disconnected
IP address: Unavailable

I did manage to get an IP address followed by a series of IPv6 links.

I don't trust my current home wifi connection, but it is encrypted and password-protected. How did this happen and how can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Turn off the phone completely?

Comment: How did you verify that it connected?

Comment: Kinalism - you would have to add a whole lot more information to make this a workable question, but in any case it is not a security question.

Comment: I consider this a security question because my smartphone has been compromised and I wanted to know what tools the hackers have been using.

Comment: How did I verify that it was connected? I visited websites and used Google.